# Why doesn't the Kotlin print statement require scope clarification?

Tags: java, scope, kotlin

This might be a stupid question, but I'm brand new to Kotlin.

In Java, the typical print statement is:

```
System.out.println("Goodbye cruel world!");
```

However, in Kotlin, we can just write:

```
println("Kotlin is weird but good")
```

How does Kotlin get around the scope clarification here? It's not like `println` is a language construct in Kotlin (or is it?). Am I missing something obvious here? Is there some kind of implicit import statement happening here?

Note that `println` is just an example here; there are many other similar instances in Kotlin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kotlin supports [top level functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#function-scope), and [`println`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/println.html) is simply declared as one, you can see its source [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/1.2.0/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/io/Console.kt#L71).

These can be used without any qualifiers if the package they're in is imported, and the basic Kotlin packages are [imported by default](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/packages.html#default-imports).

Answer (score 4):

A number of packages are imported by default in every Kotlin file. See [Default Imports](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/packages.html#default-imports) in the Reference manual for a list of these packages.

One of them is [`kotlin.io.*`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/index.html) which contains the [`println`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/println.html) function. Note that `*` imports all accessible contents. `public`, the default [visibility modifier](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/visibility-modifiers.html#visibility-modifiers) for top level elements, is included with that import.

You can corroborate this by either using the Kotlin REPL and entering:

```
>>> kotlin.io.println("Hello")
```

or putting it in a `.kts` file and executing it with `kotlinc -script filename`.

Other functions, classes et cetera from the list of default imports can also be used in a similar way.